# Excel formula for if negative then zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for formula if this cell results in a negative number then I want the cell to equal zero, else show the positive number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use MAX:

```
=MAX(0,yourformula)
```

When your formula return a negative the max will return the 0 instead.  But when positive it will return the value of the formula.

Comment: Thank you.  Works great.

Comment: Got another question you may be able to help with, is there a way to add this formula into a cell that has writing, something like: Equivalent Transition - =MAX(0,yourformula)

Comment: @RickD `="Equivalent Transition - " & MAX(0,yourformula)`